# aws data migration service not picking any source table

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I created aws dms (data migration service) task but task is not picking any source schema table.

Both source and target end points are successful. I first tried Sybase to Oracle migration then to trouble-shoot Oracle to Oracle migration task.

In both cases it didn't pick any table.

I have tried by giving specific table name and also % in but it is not picking any table in both cases.

Both source and target end points use admin account and also source table has select to public grant.

Kindly suggest. I have attached jsons and images.

Thanks in advance.

[image: task status]

[image: table name]

[image: % in table name]

Attached below is json for table mapping and complete task:

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "rule-type": "selection",
      "rule-id": "1",
      "rule-name": "1",
      "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "SRC_ORCL",
        "table-name": "%"
      },
      "rule-action": "include"
    }
  ]
}
```

Task Json

```
{
"TargetMetadata": {
    "TargetSchema": "dbadmin",
    "SupportLobs": true,
    "FullLobMode": false,
    "LobChunkSize": 0,
    "LimitedSizeLobMode": true,
    "LobMaxSize": 32,
    "InlineLobMaxSize": 0,
    "LoadMaxFileSize": 0,
    "ParallelLoadThreads": 0,
    "ParallelLoadBufferSize": 0,
    "BatchApplyEnabled": false,
    "TaskRecoveryTableEnabled": false,
    "ParallelLoadQueuesPerThread": 0,
    "ParallelApplyThreads": 0,
    "ParallelApplyBufferSize": 0,
    "ParallelApplyQueuesPerThread": 0
},
"FullLoadSettings": {
    "TargetTablePrepMode": "DROP_AND_CREATE",
    "CreatePkAfterFullLoad": false,
    "StopTaskCachedChangesApplied": false,
    "StopTaskCachedChangesNotApplied": false,
    "MaxFullLoadSubTasks": 8,
    "TransactionConsistencyTimeout": 600,
    "CommitRate": 10000
},
"Logging": {
    "EnableLogging": false,
    "LogComponents": [
        {
            "Id": "TRANSFORMATION",
            "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
        },
        {
            "Id": "SOURCE_UNLOAD",
            "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
        },
        {
            "Id": "IO",
            "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
        },
        {
            "Id": "TARGET_LOAD",
            "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
        },
        {
            "Id": "PERFORMANCE",
            "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
        },
        {
            "Id": "SOURCE_CAPTURE",
            "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
        },
        {
            "Id": "SORTER",
            "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
        },
        {
            "Id": "REST_SERVER",
            "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
        },
        {
            "Id": "VALIDATOR_EXT",
            "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
        },
        {
            "Id": "TARGET_APPLY",
            "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
        },
        {
            "Id": "TASK_MANAGER",
            "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
        },
        {
            "Id": "TABLES_MANAGER",
            "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
        },
        {
            "Id": "METADATA_MANAGER",
            "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
        },
        {
            "Id": "FILE_FACTORY",
            "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
        },
        {
            "Id": "COMMON",
            "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
        },
        {
            "Id": "ADDONS",
            "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
        },
        {
            "Id": "DATA_STRUCTURE",
            "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
        },
        {
            "Id": "COMMUNICATION",
            "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
        },
        {
            "Id": "FILE_TRANSFER",
            "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
        }
    ],
    "CloudWatchLogGroup": null,
    "CloudWatchLogStream": null
},
"ControlTablesSettings": {
    "historyTimeslotInMinutes": 5,
    "ControlSchema": "TGT_ORCL",
    "HistoryTimeslotInMinutes": 5,
    "HistoryTableEnabled": true,
    "SuspendedTablesTableEnabled": true,
    "StatusTableEnabled": true
},
"StreamBufferSettings": {
    "StreamBufferCount": 3,
    "StreamBufferSizeInMB": 8,
    "CtrlStreamBufferSizeInMB": 5
},
"ChangeProcessingDdlHandlingPolicy": {
    "HandleSourceTableDropped": true,
    "HandleSourceTableTruncated": true,
    "HandleSourceTableAltered": true
},
"ErrorBehavior": {
    "DataErrorPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
    "DataTruncationErrorPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
    "DataErrorEscalationPolicy": "SUSPEND_TABLE",
    "DataErrorEscalationCount": 0,
    "TableErrorPolicy": "SUSPEND_TABLE",
    "TableErrorEscalationPolicy": "STOP_TASK",
    "TableErrorEscalationCount": 0,
    "RecoverableErrorCount": -1,
    "RecoverableErrorInterval": 5,
    "RecoverableErrorThrottling": true,
    "RecoverableErrorThrottlingMax": 1800,
    "ApplyErrorDeletePolicy": "IGNORE_RECORD",
    "ApplyErrorInsertPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
    "ApplyErrorUpdatePolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
    "ApplyErrorEscalationPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
    "ApplyErrorEscalationCount": 0,
    "ApplyErrorFailOnTruncationDdl": false,
    "FullLoadIgnoreConflicts": true,
    "FailOnTransactionConsistencyBreached": false,
    "FailOnNoTablesCaptured": false
},
"ChangeProcessingTuning": {
    "BatchApplyPreserveTransaction": true,
    "BatchApplyTimeoutMin": 1,
    "BatchApplyTimeoutMax": 30,
    "BatchApplyMemoryLimit": 500,
    "BatchSplitSize": 0,
    "MinTransactionSize": 1000,
    "CommitTimeout": 1,
    "MemoryLimitTotal": 1024,
    "MemoryKeepTime": 60,
    "StatementCacheSize": 50
},
"PostProcessingRules": null,
"CharacterSetSettings": null,
"LoopbackPreventionSettings": null,
"BeforeImageSettings": null
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It worked, After I made below changes

i) Sybase source end point to use database as pubs2. 
ii) In task specified % in both Schema and table name.